# Apparently no error in update query but the record is not updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

this is my code for usersedit.php and the other one is for users-edit-action.php
after updating its saying that the data is succfully updated but it doesnot change anything in  mysql.. please help me figureout the problem, thankyou
users-edit.php

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php"); ?>
<?php
if ($_SESSION["isadmin"])
{

$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }

mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$accountid=$_GET["id"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE (id='".$accountid."')");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
$lastname = $row['lastname'];
$email=$row['email'];
$type=$row['type'];
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Edit User</title>
<link rel="StyleSheet" href="../admin/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head>


<body>
<?php include("../admin/includes/header.php"); ?>
<?php include("../admin/includes/nav.php"); ?>
<?php include("../admin/includes/manage-users-aside.php"); ?>
<div id="maincontent">

<div id="breadcrumbs">
<a href="">Home</a> >
<a href="">Manage Users</a> >
<a href="">List Users</a> >
Edit User
</div>
<h2>Edit User</h2>

<form method="post" action="users-edit-action.php">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $accountid; ?>" name="id" />
<label>Email/Username:</label><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;     ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo     $password;?>" /><br /><br />
<label>First Name:</label><input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo      $firstname; ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>" /><br /><br />
<label>Type:</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="S" <?php if ($type == 'S') echo     'checked="checked"'; ?> />Student<br />
<input type="radio" name="type" value="T" <?php if ($type == 'T') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> /> Teacher<br />

<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
<?php include("../admin/includes/footer.php"); ?>
</html>
<?php

}    else
{
header("Location: ".$fullpath."login/unauthorized.php");
}
?>
```

this is users-edit-action.php

```
<?php include("../includes/config.php");?>
<?php

$id=$_POST["id"];
$firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lastname=$_POST["lastname"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$type=$_POST["type"];


$con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }


mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
$query=("UPDATE accounts SET firstname='".$firstname."' , lastname='".$lastname."         ,password='".$password."' , email='".$email."' type='".$type."' WHERE (id='".$id."')");
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "User has been updated Successfully!!";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

please help me figure out and solve the problem

Comment: can you post here what is the value of `$result`?

Comment: You are not escaping any of the variables you are constructing your query out of, do they contain quotes? Please dump and inspect $query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape column names that is a **[reserved keyword of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)**

```
$query=("UPDATE accounts 
         SET firstname='" . $firstname . "'   ,
             lastname='" . $lastname . "      ,
              `password`='" . $password . "'  ,          
              email='" . $email . "'          ,            // <== forgot comma
              type='" . $type . "' WHERE (id='".$id."')
        ");
```

`Password` should be escaped. 
You forgot to add comma between `email` and `type`.

Your current query is prone to **[SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. Use **[PDO](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)** or **[MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)**

Example of using PDO extension:

```
<?php

    $query = "UPDATE accounts 
               SET firstname = ?,
                   lastname = ?,
                   `PassWord` = ?,          
                   email = ?,          
                   type = ? 
            WHERE id = ?
        ";

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $lastname);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $password);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $type);
    $stmt->bindParam(6, $id);

    $stmt->execute();
    echo ($stmt) ? "Successful" : "Error Occured";

?>
```

this will allow you to insert records with single quotes.

Comment: Add result check for `mysql_query()` : `echo (!$result) ? "Error" : "User has been updated Successfully!!";`

Comment: this is how i canged the code as u said.but still it is not updating the records in database...i never had this problem before..please help

Comment: $con=mysql_connect($dbserver,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }mysql_select_db($dbname, $con);
    $result=("UPDATE accounts
         SET firstname='" . $firstname . "'   ,
             lastname='" . $lastname . "      ,
             'password'='" . $password . "'  ,
             email='" . $email . "'          ,
             type='" . $type . "' WHERE (id='".$id."') ");
    echo "User has been updated Successfully!!";
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>